# jQuery IF anchor source is not hash then

Tags: jquery, hash, if-statement, anchor

I've got a bunch of images wrapped in dummy anchors that have their source set to #. I'm writing a function that checks if the source is not a hash and gives it a lil some special. Seems something is off.. Help?

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/zR95t/

```
if (!$(this).attr('href', '#')) {
    //blahblah not a hash
} else {
    //do some other thing
}
```

Comment: The code in your fiddle makes no sense. When is it being called and what's calling it? What does $(this) refer to? You're calling event.preventDefault() on something that isn't an event listener.

Comment: copy/paste error.http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/zR95t/1/
you shouldn't downvote the question as if it isn't a legitimate question that hasn't been asked on the site before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if ($(this).attr('href') != '#') {
    //blahblah not a hash
} else {
    //do some other thing
}
```

Otherwise you would be setting '#' as the href attribute, see: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: ah, perfect. Technically shouldn't it be !== ?

Comment: in this cas there shouldn't be any difference:
http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/comparison_operators.html